# Не работает border

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, написал таблицу, в ней две строки, и каждой строке border-top+border-bottom, но это почему то не работает, что я делаю не так?

```css
.about-us__section-content-row {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<table class="about-us__section-content-table">
  <tr class="about-us__section-content-row">
    <td class="about-us__section-content-column">
      время в пути
    </td>
    <td class="about-us__section-content-column">
      расстояние
    </td>
    <td class="about-us__section-content-column">
      в невесомости
    </td>
    <td class="about-us__section-content-column">
      стоимость
    </td>
    <td class="about-us__section-content-column">
      вернешься?
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="about-us__section-content-row">
    <td class="about-us__section-content-column">
      1
      <span>час</span>
    </td>
    <td class="about-us__section-content-column">
      80
      <span>км</span>
    </td>
    <td class="about-us__section-content-column">
      4-5
      <span>мин</span>
    </td>
    <td class="about-us__section-content-column">
      250
      <span>тыс. дол</span>
    </td>
    <td class="about-us__section-content-column">
      99
      <span>%</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Для `<tr>` нельзя дать `border`. Используйте на ячейках.

Comment: У автора на видео это получается сделать, но видео годичной давности, что то за год поменялось в CSS?

Comment: Никогда нельзя было этого делать. Вы что-то путаете или автор что-то недорассказал.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/live/xj9C_taVA6E?feature=share&t=2761
Вот, смотрите

Answer (score 2):

На таблицу накладываем стиль, и все заработает.

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

Comment: Опередили) Оказывается это может повлиять на бордеры.